# Android ListView does not expand

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have an activity with more controls: a Spinner, 2 editboxes, a button some textviews and a listview, followed by another button. All in a vertical layout.

OnClick of the first button, I add a new Item to the listview (based on the other editboxes values and spinner values). This way, the listview keeps growing.
I want to know if there is any way to make the height of the listview to expand automatically after each adding.
Also The bottom buttons should remain at the bottom after the expansion.

I want this because my listview is very small due to the many controls on the layout. It barely shows 2 items at once. So the user cannot see all the items added at once, he has to scroll inside this **2 item listview** to see them all. And that looks bad and stupid. And also the user will **HAVE to know** that there are more than 2 items in the list, because without seeing them directly, he can assume 2 items is all there is and the app does not work because no new items appear.
I hope I made myself clear.

Please tell me if it is possible or what would be the best approach in this case?

My layout is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".NewStuff" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Page title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Choose item" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:text="Property 1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Property 2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="Add to listview" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Save listview contents" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get your listview to take up the remaining height not assigned to the other buttons and spinners?

Answer (score 3):

Use a LinearLayout to hold everything, and use layout_weight on the ListView to accomplish this:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/listView1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
          android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
          android:layout_below="@+id/button2"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

you need a custom listview.

```
public class ExpandedListView extends ListView {

private android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params;
private int old_count = 0;

public ExpandedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (getCount() != old_count) {
        old_count = getCount();
        params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getCount() * (old_count > 0 ? getChildAt(0).getHeight() + 2 : 0);
        setLayoutParams(params);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
   if(ev.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
      return true;
   return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

}

this listview will grow with the number of its children.
in your xml you have to use

```
<your.path.ExpandedListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
```

hope this will help

Comment: Thank you very much. This is by far a better solution.

Comment: @Azizi i updated the calculation of the height so a list with many items is displayed correctly. use params.height = getCount() * (old_count > 0 ? getChildAt(0).getHeight() + 2 : 0);

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have too many items on your screen, remember that Android runs on a large number of screen configurations. So on some devices there will be room for more than two items but on others there may be less than two. So I suggest the following solutions:

1. If there are not that many items and they don't involve displaying large graphics, you can change ListView to a LinearLayout, and insert all of your items dynamically. Then encapsulate the whole view inside a ScrollerView so users can scroll anywhere to see the complete list.
2. Show the result in a different Activity/fragment, which has the bonus effect of emphasizing the data the user is searching for

**[Edit]**

It's actually quite simple, the basic idea is to:

1. for each item, inflate the desired view and set its layout param
2. add it to the parent view
3. repeats step 1 & 2

For example:

```
//the base LinearLayout that you want to insert items
LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) fragView.findViewById(R.id.booking_content);

//for each item in the LinearLayout
for(int i=0; i<itemsList.size(); i++) {
    //inflate layout as you normally would for a ListView
    ViewGroup base = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.include_no_movie, null);
    //sets the layout parameter of the child view
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //adds the view
    content.addView(base, param);
}
```

Comment: I like your suggestion with the LinearLayout inside a Scroller, but I do not know how to create items that would mimic the listview, and most importantly, how would I parse those dynamic "items" at the end when the user wants to save his work by pressing the bottom button?